# RegEx to get data between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone please help me with a regular expression to get match data between two strings?

I have data in the below format

```
/* BEGIN EXAMPLE SECTION */
"One" : "1",
"Two" : "2",
/* END EXAMPLE SECTION */
```

I want the output to be:

```
"One" : "1",
"Two" : "2",
```

I am using a gulp strip code task to strip out the comments and get the data within them.

The start_comment and end_comment require a regular expression, to match the starting of the comment section and the end of the comment section respectively.                                                                                              The regular expression in the file is:

```
var re = new RegExp("([\\t ]*\\/\\* ?BEGIN ANGULAR SECTION?\\*\\/)[\\s\\S]*?(\\/\\* ?END ANGULAR SECTION?\\*\\/[\\t ]*\\n?)", "g");
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and the research you did before asking this question.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What language are you using to get the data?

Comment: I am using gulp strip code for stripping out some line out of my file

Answer (score 0):

If all on one line, you can try this: `/.*/(.*)/`
You are looking for the data between the second and third Slash(/).  The paren's give you that grouping.

If you have multiple lines, you will need to integrate a language.

Comment: You pattern is missing backslash to escape that slash in it.

Comment: Thank you for the response acree , but the data is not on one line .